# Use NgClass with a custom Pipe

Tags: angular

I'm trying to assign a custom class on a span based on a result given from a `pipe trasform`. Sadly, I'm not getting it to work.

Here's the scenario. I'm itering this object in a `ngFor` statement:

```
"documents": [
  {
    "document_ext": "pdf"
  } ,
  {
    "document_ext": "doc"
  }
]
```

While itering I want to assign a custom class based on the `document_ext`. but this is causing me following error:

> Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at
>   column 0 in [{{doc?.document_ext | documentaleType}}]

The html code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let doc of documentList">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="doc-type">
      <span class="row-icon" [ngClass]="{{doc?.document_ext | documentaleType}}"> 
      </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And the simple pipe just return a standard value for now:

```
export class DocumentaleTypePipe {
    transform(ext: string): string {
        return "p3-018-dummy";
    }
}
```

I don't want to call a function, that's why I've choose to use a `pipe`. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

> EDIT

Solved this way:

```
<span class="row-icon" [ngClass]="[doc.document_ext ? (doc.document_ext | documentaleType) : 'p3-018-dummy']"></span>
```

Comment: Every time you have [someProperty]="...", then the value is always an angular expression, and you must thus not use double curly braces.

Comment: You can't use a combination of [] and {{}} as in `[ngClass]="{{doc?.document_ext | documentaleType}}"`, since both will make it an expression instead of just interpreting the text.

Answer (score 4):

**PIPE**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getClass'
})
export class GetClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any, args?: any): any {
    return obj['document_ext'];
  }
}
```

**COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public documents = [
    {
      "document_ext": "pdf"
    },
    {
      "document_ext": "doc"
    }
  ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let doc of documents" [ngClass]="doc | getClass">test</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pdf {
  color:red
}

.doc {
  color:green
}
```

Here's a live demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/use-ngclass-with-a-custom-pipe

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a combination of `[ngClass]` and `{{function()}}` as in `[ngClass]="{{doc?.document_ext | documentaleType}}"`, since both will make it an expression instead of just interpreting the text.

Try using `[ngClass]="doc?.document_ext | documentaleType"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite **`ngClass`** like `[ngClass]="{'class': true}"`

In your code, you have to write ngClass as below

```
  <span class="row-icon" [ngClass]="{'pdf-class': doc.document_ext == 'pdf'}"> 
    {{doc.document_ext}}
  </span>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lqcw6)